# Неожиданный выход из цикла при работе с каналом

Tags: linux, c, fifo

Есть два примера, один на запись в именованный канал FIFO, другой на чтение:

Запись:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int fd, d = 2;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo3";
    char buf[MAX_BUF], src[] = "1234567890qwertyuiop";

    for (i = 900000; i > 0; i--)
    {
        usleep(1000);

        // mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
        if((mkfifo(myfifo, 0666)) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Невозможно создать fifo\n");
        } 
        else
        {
            mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
        }

        fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
        d = 1 + (int)(10.0 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0));
        src[0] = src[d];
        printf("%s\n", src);
        write(fd, src, sizeof(src));
        close(fd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Чтение:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUF 999999

int main()
{
    int i,d=0;
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo3";
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    for (i = 900000; i > 0; i--)
    {
        usleep(1000);

        if ((fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)) < 0)
        {
            printf("Cannot open FIFO\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            d++;
            fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
            read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
            printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
            printf("шаг= %d", d); //счетчик, сколько раз я прочитал из fifo
            close(fd);
        }

    }
    // return 0; чтобы не выходил из цикла
}
```

На 1021 шаге при чтении выходит из цикла, почему?

Comment: Прямо вот аккуратно выходит и как-то сообщает об этом? Или все же последнее сообщение, которое Вы видите это `шаг=511`?  Если второе, то дескрипторы на процесс закончились (close в конце шага забыли) и какую то часть кода с выходом Вы не привели.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, теперь выходит из цикла при шаге 1021.

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под выходом?

Comment: Вы бы сначала **русским языком** описали, что нужно сделать. Глядишь, после этого и программу бы правильно сделали. И не мешает нормально отформатироваать код в вопросе.

Comment: Ну, по сути я хочу, чтобы программа постоянно записывала данные в myfifo, а вторая постоянно считывала из myfifo данные. А в целом, я хочу получить данные из fifo, которые записывает usermode программа, а считывал модуль ядра

Comment: В самом деле хотите в цикле делать mkfifo/open или только write/read?

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выходит из цикла потому что стоит лимит на открытие файловых дескрипторов в 1024 (по умолчанию). Больше 1024 фаловых дескрипторов открыть нельзя. Или лимит нужно увеличить или в программе не открывать файлов больше лимита в 1024.

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь все понятно